# Jeasyui Datagrid Pagination Issues with second page only

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, datagrid, jquery-easyui

I'm pulling my hair over JeasyUI datagrid.

It's calculating the number of rows correctly. Currently i have 22 rows, which gives 3 pages in the grid. The second page does not display though. I don't get it. The third page works

I'm strongly suspecting my SQL, and the offset and limit but what's wrong? I set $offset and $rows like this (as per the example from jeasyui)

```
$page = isset($_POST['page']) ? intval($_POST['page']) : 1;
$rows = isset($_POST['rows']) ? intval($_POST['rows']) : 10;
$offset = ($page-1)*$rows;
```

To get the data I'm using this select

```
$rs = mysql_query("select z.list_name as name, z.list_pointsPerHour as PPH, list_takeoverPoints as takeover from zone z, tempzones tz where z.list_id = tz.zoneid  limit $offset,$rows");
```

If I set $rows to 20 in the file and run the php from the commandline, it gives nothing. If I leave it at 10 it gives 10 and happily reports 22 total

Hacking the SQL into the mysql console and using fixed values for offset and limit works.

My site is on: http://ghost.debruin.se/turf/datagrid/datagrid2_demo.html

And this is the example I'm failing with http://www.jeasyui.com/tutorial/datagrid/datagrid2.php

Answer (score 0):

so this was all me. I have latin1 in my database and php expected utf-8. Forced utf-8 on the ouput and problem solved.